# manipulating instance itself by its instance methods

Tags: python, class, self

I wonder if there is something similar to,
say:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def swap(self):
...         self = 'I am swapped'
... 
>>> abc=A()
>>> abc
<__main__.A object at 0x028B6130>
>>> abc.swap
<bound method A.swap of <__main__.A object at 0x028B6130>>
>>> abc.swap()
>>> abc
<__main__.A object at 0x028B6130>
>>> type(abc)
<class '__main__.A'>
```

see, it's type is not str, but Class A.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this (in almost any programming language). Not sure on the _why_ though.

Comment: this is a pretty bad design pattern... one of those just because you can doesnt mean you should ... a better option would be looking into the factory design pattern

Comment: @macek it actually is possible ...

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about _instance_ methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a terrible idea ... I do not advocate ever doing this ... In fact you should avoid at all costs ... look at using a Factory design pattern instead ...

```
>>> class A:
...    def swap(self):
...      self.__class__ = B
...
>>> class B:
...   pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.swap()
>>> a
<__main__.B instance at 0x02C43E18>
>>>
```

Comment: I agree ... but it does answer the question ... and i put a pretty good disclaimer at the begining ...

Answer (score 3):

You are confused - there is nothing special about assigning the name by using

```
self = 'I am swapped'
```

This is just binding the name `self` to a string object and it is acting as a *local variable* here. You are not mutating the parent object at all.

In fact, what you attempted is not used in Python because it's a strongly typed language. Instead, you would just make `swap` return a value, and then reassign the same variable name to the returned object in the outer scope.

Maybe this is easier to explain with code, instead of:

```
a.swap()
```

You would have:

```
a = a.swap()
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a convention. An instance of a class is what is handed to its functions in the first argument and you could call it whatever you like and you can do whatever you like to the local namespace in your particular function. See:

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(hats):
...         print hats
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f()
<__main__.A instance at 0x100466908>
```

So yes, you can manipulate `self` in a class method, but since `self` itself doesn't actually mean anything, there's no real point. You should(n't) do what Joran suggested.